# What is maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in build.gradle file meaning?

Tags: maven, build.gradle

What is maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in build.gradle file meaning?
Do I have control over project or I depend on jitpack.io developer account/libraries?

Answer (score 0):

[jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/docs/) compile source code from [github](https://github.com/)
By adding this repository to your project, you can use public's github repository in your project.

I don't know if it is possible to use a private repository requiring an account.